Power dissipation in an IC
Here is LM741 op amp circuit in Figure 1. The amplifier has two power supplies \$V_{cc}\$ and -\$V_{ee}\$. The up arrows are connected to the positive power supply \$V_{cc}\$ which is +15 V. Current flows from positive power supply to the up arrow. The down arrows are connected to the negative power supply -\$V_{ee}\$ which is -15 V. Current flows from down arrows to the negative power supply -\$V_{ee}\$. The power supplied by the positive power supply is absorbed by the circuit. The currents going into the negative power supply seem to transfer power to the negative power supply which means charging the negative power supply.

$$Figure 1$$
The book 'Microelectronic circuits, Sedra and smith, 7e, Oxford university press" says that power dissipation in the circuit is only due to the positive power supply in some places which is (\$V_{cc}\$) (currents originating from \$V_{cc}\$). In another place, the book says that power dissipated in the circuit is sum of (\$V_{cc}\$) (currents originating from \$V_{cc}\$) + (\$V_{ee}\$) (currents going into -\$V_{ee}\$).

$$Figure 2$$
The collector currents of all BJTs in \$Figure 1\$ are given in \$Figure 2\$ in µA.
What is the correct method to calculate power dissipation in the circuit which means power dissipated in all BJTs?
Reference:
Microeelectronic circuits -Theory and applications , 7e, Sedra and smith, OUP India, pages 929 and 937.

Think of the opamp as load like a simple resistor.
The power dissipation of any load is defined by the voltage over the load and current through it.
With +/- 15V supplies there is 30V over the load so that is what you use.

I used this expression, ($V_{cc}$)(Currents originating from $V_{cc}$) + ($V_{ee}$)(Currents going into -$V_{ee}$) ,  to calculate power dissipation in the circuit as current at both ends of any transistor are different with $h_{fe}$ finite for each BJT. This result is approximately same as  ($V_{cc}$ + $V_{ee}$)(Currents originating from $V_{cc}$) .

I don't see how that is related but the whole circuit is just one load, all the currents flowing in it has to either come from a supply terminal or go to a supply terminal. Also depending on your book edition (international or not) the page numbers may differ.

I will just use to this expression, ($V_{cc}$ + $V_{ee}$)(Currents originating from $V_{cc}$),  for calculating power dissipation in the circuit.

@AmitM Vcc + Vee sums to 0, so you likely have an error in the formula.

I meant the magnitude of Vee which is |Vee| . In figure 1, Vee =15v . -Vee = -15V is the negative voltage rail.

Made with microcap v12.
For this task, you could use the file "uA741.cir" included with microcap.
Microcap calculates the full powers by "definition".
Here, it should be 72 mW under +15/-15 V.


The circuit in Figure 1 omits the resistors and their power dissipation. So the value of calculation in Microcap is higher.

@AmitM That's good, though :) That's what the real chip does. You can always ignore the resistor dissipation if you wish when calculating the total. At your own peril.

The size of a layout in Microcap is too small. How to make it bigger?

@Antonio51 Your "this file" is missing.

No, it is included with microcap v12.


What is the correct method to calculate power dissipation in the circuit which means power dissipated in all BJTs?

Assume no load is connected and no input signal is applied to either inputs, and only Vcc and Vee are applied. In this case, the total loss comes from the biasing only.
Vcc and Vee has a common ground. But as you can see, the circuit doesn't have any connection to that ground so its local reference is Vee therefore the biasing currents flow from Vcc to Vee and all you can do is to calculate the losses in quiescent mode and you'll see that both supplies will come into play.
If you configure the op amp so its output voltage is positive, and if you connect a load across the output and the ground (which is the common point of positive and negative rails) and you'll see that the load current will be supplied from the positive rail (Vcc). In this case, there's going to be a disipation due to the Vcc (apart from the biasing/quiescent loss).
